# passing string length from main to the same class above in a array

Tags: java

PALINDROME CHECK

I need to pass the string length from my main method to the class where there is a character array whose length has to be defined ...which is my string legth itself ....

```java
char ch[] = new char[stringSize];// this is not working

public class PalindromeChecker {


    static char queue[]=new char [100];

    static char deQueue[]=new char[100];

    static int size=0,front=0,rear=0;


    public static void addRear (char ch)
    {   
        queue[rear]=ch;
        rear=(rear+1);  // for cicular array
        size=size+1;

    }



    public static void addFront()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<queue.length;i++)
        {
            deQueue[i]=queue[(queue.length-1)-i];
        }
    }

    public static void show()
    {
        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0;i<rear;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(queue[i]+" ");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);




        boolean status=true;

        System.out.println("Enter your word for Palindrome check :");
        String userData=scanner.nextLine();

        int stringSize=userData.length();


        System.out.println();
        char ch[]=userData.toCharArray();

        // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ch));

        for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++)
        {
            addRear(ch[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("\nThe filled deQueue is : ");
        show();

        addFront();

        System.out.println("\n\nNew filled deQueue");
//      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(deQueue));

        for(int i=0;i<rear;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(deQueue[i]+" ");
        }

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {   
            if(deQueue[i]==queue[i])
            {
                status= true;
            }
            else
            {
                status=false;
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Not a palindrome !");
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
        if(status)
        {
            System.out.println("\nPALINDROME !");
        }


    }
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Wait... are you trying to declare the variable outside of the class? That is not possible in Java.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking how to pass the length of user input String to char array constructor, then since you are using static variables, use a method that initializes the arrays and accept int as argument, like so:

```
static void initArrays(int inputSize){
  queue = new char [inputSize];
  deQueue = new char[inputSize];
}
```

When you have your input String just call:

```
initArrays(inputString.length());
```

Answer (score 1):

See the below code in main method:

```
 PalindromeChecker.deQueue =  new char [stringSize];
            PalindromeChecker.queue = new char [stringSize];
```

Complete modified code:

```
public class PalindromeChecker {


        static char queue[];

        static char deQueue[];

        static int size=0,front=0,rear=0;


        public static void addRear (char ch)
        {   
            queue[rear]=ch;
            rear=(rear+1);  // for cicular array
            size=size+1;

        }



        public static void addFront()
        {
            for(int i=0;i<queue.length;i++)
            {
                deQueue[i]=queue[(queue.length-1)-i];
            }
        }

        public static void show()
        {
            System.out.println();
            for(int i=0;i<rear;i++)
            {
                System.out.print(queue[i]+" ");
            }

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);




            boolean status=true;

            System.out.println("Enter your word for Palindrome check :");
            String userData=scanner.nextLine();

            int stringSize=userData.length();
            PalindromeChecker.deQueue =  new char [stringSize];
            PalindromeChecker.queue = new char [stringSize];

            System.out.println();
            char ch[]=userData.toCharArray();

            // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ch));

            for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++)
            {
                addRear(ch[i]);
            }

            System.out.println("\nThe filled deQueue is : ");
            show();

            addFront();

            System.out.println("\n\nNew filled deQueue");
    //      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(deQueue));

            for(int i=0;i<rear;i++)
            {
                System.out.print(deQueue[i]+" ");
            }

            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {   
                if(deQueue[i]==queue[i])
                {
                    status= true;
                }
                else
                {
                    status=false;
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Not a palindrome !");
                    break;
                }
            }

            System.out.println();
            if(status)
            {
                System.out.println("\nPALINDROME !");
            }


        }}
```